# There are resources Jenkins was not able to dispose automatically - concerning?

Tags: jenkins

After running different jobs I sometimes get this message in Jenkins:
"There are resources Jenkins was not able to dispose automatically."
I can then click the link provided and there is no additional information there.  The jobs run fine, the workspace is as expected, the jobs folder looks normal.  Is this something I should be concerned with?

Comment: Do you run jobs on your master, or on agents? If on agents, are they automatically created/destroyed or do they stay around 24/7?

Comment: I _think_ it's master.  It's a very basic Jenkins setup.  The builds check out of git (master) and then usually just copy/paste files to a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned you believe all the work happens on your master, not an agent. This may negate what I'm about to say but it might help for troubleshooting anyway;

We have a master/agent setup and often get those warnings. We found it was because one of our jobs created files with permission settings that didn't give Jenkins permission to delete them. Sometimes we could track down the exact files; sometimes it was blank, like you said.

We figured out that the blank ones were happening because the agent was taken offline once it was done with its jobs, and then deleted. No agent = no files. Maybe your master deletes its workspace periodically and creates the same effect?

Either way the solution for us was to change the permissions on the affected files, and we stopped getting the messages.

Answer (score 2):

This error came when jenkins tries to delete cleanup folder but cant delete may be due to permission error or other.

To check the files which Jenkins is trying but not able to delete:
sudo find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/*ws-cleanup*/ -user root

To delete:
sudo find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/*ws-cleanup*/ -user root -delete

To avoid add the delete command whose job files are giving problem.

Regards
DevOpsBro